# How to check state changing between two components after button click?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have 2 components for this task.First one is my wrapper component and the second one is component for buttons.

I am clicking one of the buttons of my button component and it changes state in my wrapper component.

Now how can i bring that whole action in Jest(Enzyme) environment?

```
it('should update state', () => {
      const onButtonClickMock = jest.fn();
      const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>)
      const buttons = shallow(<Colors onClick={onButtonClickMock} colors={['gray', 'black', 'white']}/>);


      const d = buttons.find('div#buttons');
      const b = d.find('button.btn');
      b.at(1).simulate('click');//Pick second button from bunch and click

      wrapper.update();

      expect(onButtonClickMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);//This works
      expect(component2.state(['selection'])).toBe(1);

})
```

Comment: This won't work because there is no relationship between`Colors` and `MyComponent`. Both of them are being rendered separately.

Comment: Maybe yes but what exactly are you trying to test here? Can you rely on user interaction test only? Is state update visible to use in anyway via UI?

Comment: @HardikModha And what you are suggesting to do?

Comment: @HardikModha I want to test is state changing after clicking button.

Comment: Don't test that the state is being updated or not rather test what the user would expect to happen once the button is clicked.

Comment: Is this state change being resulting into some UI change which is visible to the user? You should rather test that

Comment: @HardikModha Yeah i can do that but how i can do one thing in one component and then check changes in another after let’s say the same click.How i can track that ?

Comment: @HardikModha after clicking the button state of the wrapper component changes and it affects of image change in another component because Image component is connected with wrapper component with props.

Comment: No, i need some help with it.Can you give some suggestions?

Comment: It's kinda integration. You can use enzyme's mount.

Comment: Can you add a stripped-down version of the code for `MyComponent` and `Colors` to show how they interact?  That will help you get a better answer.